# raft based consensus for private transaction

Tags: quorum

According to my understanding, in raft based consensus, leader is the minter who notifies all the follower to add new block in blockchain. In private transaction betweeen two nodes A and B of Quorum, will the leader be from A and B or it can be any node in Network?

Answer (score 1):

In case of `Quorum` private transactions update the private `StateDB` of participants involved(A and B). Consensus will be achieved by checking the root hash of private `StateDB` of participants involved(A and B). Other participants of the blockchain network(including leader) will not be involved in the process of validating transactions as they will receive a `NotARecipient` message and will skip the Transaction - it will not update its Private `StateDB`.

Answer (score 1):

@digya, in Quorum Raft mode, all txns are minted by the leader and the leader does not have to be part of the private grouping. What happens is that originating node for private contract will receive a new txn, will talk to its private txn manager and send the payload (data) off to the involved parties, receive confirmation from private txn manager with public payload (hash signature) and place that onto public chain as the txn. The leader then mints this public txn, sends off the block to everyone and parties to the private state will query their own private txn managers to get actual payload.